# Is it possible to disable auto-closing brackets inside quoted strings in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can the automatic completion of braces be turned off when typing text within quotes in VS Code? The provided image does not show any option to disable this specifically within quotes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d85qA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet currently is using `"languageDefined"`. Then the behaviour will be up to the extension providing language support for whatever language you are in. From a quick test, with that setting, you'll get the behaviour you want in JS, but not in many other languages.